# double assignment in single instruction

Tags: java

This may sound crazy, but i'm curious to know if it is possible to use a single instruction to modify the values of two different variables.
For example, suppose i have this code (**x and y are int variables**):

```
if(x < 0) {
   y -= x ;
   x = 0;
}
```

***If x is equal to -1***,  i would obtain the same result by doing the following :

```
if(x < 0) y -= x++;
```

Is there a way to generalise the previous result? I tried with the instruction :

```
if(x < 0) y -=x-=x;
```

But, while x at the end is equal to 0, y won't be modified. What i'm missing ?

**EDIT**

I thought (i was wrong probably) it was clear that my question was purely theoretical.
I know that this way of doing should be avoided. I was just curious :).

Comment: Probably because this is a hack that will result in future maintainers of the code cursing you to eternity and possibly coming to your door in the middle of the night armed with a flamethrower and murderous intent.  Don't write horrible code like this just to save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(x < 0) x = (y -= x) - y;
```

It's fine to try tricks like these for a challenge. However, **Don't use** this type of code in your actual code as it'll create confusion for others.

Comment: @Ansharja please never use this in real life code. The days of coding cool and cryptic onliners are over. Please write **clean code**!

Comment: `x = x < 0 ? (y -= x) - y : x`